# Google Spreadsheet change dropdown options based on cell value

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have 2 dropdown lists:

[image]

I would like the dropdown options inside `B2,3` to be driven by the value of `A2,3`.

[image]

So, in the above example,  I would ideally like

```
B2: to contain values from E2:E40
B3: to contain values from F2:F40
```

I have looked at condition-formatting, but this is the only style. Both A2 and B2 are driving with similar-looking `Data-Validation` rules as here:
[image]

Testable example:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RmGfrO4d9pzeDKONjimwJ0pbr5tYXH-d/edit#gid=229417886

{edit}

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(E2=Config!C3, Config!F2:Config!F40, Config!H2:Config!H40))`

The values will indeed update when i change the values in the Game System drop down, however rather than it display as a dropdown, it updates all of the values in `F2-F16`

[image]

Comment: updated your sheet for B2 and B3

Comment: You need to use this new range as a data validation drop down criteria.

Comment: Ah ok, so I create a seperate 2 rows inside the spreadsheet. I understand

Comment: The problem is i have over 1600 items all with their own dynamic fields. lol I've accepted your answer as it does answer the question. But any ideas for having so many items?

Comment: unfortunately, this is the only way how to deal with dependant dropdowns

Comment: Much appreciated pal!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to use **`IF`** function per each B cell for unique dropdowns

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2=G1, G2:G, H2:H))
```

will feed B2

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A3=G1, G2:G, H2:H))
```

will feed B3, etc.

[image: 0]

this way you can create custom drop-downs per selection from A column

Comment: Though I have no idea how to actually  apply this formula :)

Comment: Ah ok, I can see in the printscreen. I just find it odd that I cannt see it when in the example

Comment: !! you didn't do it in the example :)

Comment: Thanks again, just another question, I'll update the question